# Is it possible to convert index type from async to sync for existing secondary index in YDB?

Tags: ydb

I've created a table in YDB with async index using following YQL statement:

```
(sql)
create table messages 
(
    chat_id uint64,
    user_id uint64,
    posted_at uint64,
    modifed_at Datetime,
    message_text Utf8,
    message_media Json,
    views_cnt Uint64,
    index idx_user_chat_posted global sync on (user_id, chat_id, posted_at),
    primary key(chat_id, posted_at, user_id)
)
```

Is it possible to convert index type from sync to async?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently YDB doesn't support index type change.

Though it is possible to [create async index](https://ydb.tech/en/docs/yql/reference/syntax/alter_table#secondary-index) on the same set of columns with `ALTER TABLE` statement.

New async index will have another name and all the queries using sync index should be rewritten.